# Issue in creating Layout in Liferay DXP

Tags: layout, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I am trying to create a layout in Liferay DXP using themegenerator by following this link : https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-layout-templates-with-the-themes-generator-0.
On successful completion of the steps mentioned in the link, -layouttpl gets generated but .tpl file and .png file are not getting generated.
 What can be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I created layout with theme generators, but i found inside 'yourlayoutname/docroot'.

Please make sure you followed all steps, mentioned in - in document you shared link. Once you created layout, you have to define rows and columns of layout. Pls make sure you followed all instructions.